# Evalute FreeMarker template whose value is another placeholder

Tags: java, freemarker, template-engine

I have a template Hello ${user} and to evalute this I provide a **Map** with values
{user=${testUser}, testUser=me} and i expect the result to be **Hello me**.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out by <#assign inlineTemplate = user?interpret>
Hello <@inlineTemplate /> instead of Hello ${user}

Comment: You can simply write that as `<@user?interpret />`; no need for the `#assign`.